# Проблема с заголовком - присоединительное ли значение имеет "и не только"?

Tags: пунктуация

Заголовок, нависающий над подробностями функционирования бара, очень лаконичен:

**БАР И НЕ ТОЛЬКО**

Ничего не требуется?

Прецедент найден такой:

[image: О платках... и не только]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, ничего не требуется. Чаще всего в заголовках и  коротких конструкциях это не присоединение, просто однородные члены. Присоединением  "и не только" было бы в более распространённых конструкциях типа" *Бар, и не только бар,был..*. "

Присоединение обретает смысл "и **притом** не только". Вот в заголовке  "О платках... и не только" такой разъясняющий, присоединительный смысл есть, на него указывает многоточие.