# Он придет сегодня(,) и не один

Tags: пунктуация

Требуется ли в этом предложении запятая?

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440786/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8/440789#440789

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435740/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE